# How to set dynamic id to a table and append it to a div?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, typescript

I want to dynamically create 10 tables and append it in div container with class table_container.
This is the snippet I was trying, do i need to make any changes in it for my requirement?

```js
for( let i =0; i< 10; i++){
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  table.setAttribute("id", "table"+i);
  }
```

```html
<div class="table_container">
    
</div>
```

Comment: What is the problem

Comment: question is how do i append all the tables inside table_container

Comment: Try searching for how to append elements to another element.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score -1):

```js
// Get a reference to the container.
const container = document.querySelectorAll('.table_container')[0];

for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  // Create the new <table>
  const table = document.createElement('table');
  table.setAttribute("id", "table"+i);
  
  // Append it to the inside of the container.
  container.appendChild(table);
}
```